# SSRS Filter expression date OR date

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, filter, expression

I have a dataset in SSRS 2010.  It returns a value for `Start_Date` and `End_Date`.  I need to filter the dataset with the following:

```
Start_Date >= 05/04/2012 or Start_Date < 04/04/2013 or End_Date < 04/04/2013
```

I have tried:

```
Expression:=(start_date >= '05/04/2012') or (start_date < '04'04'2013') or (end_date < '05/04/2013')
Operator: =
Value: =True
```

but unfortunately it does not apply the filter selection.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not apply` Show some data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want reocords between `05/04/2012` and `' 04/04/2013'` for start date or `end date < 04/04/2013`. If that's what you want the records which have `Start_Date` between `05/04/2012` and ' 04/04/2013' then you are using the wrong operator `OR`. You should use `And` or `Between` so that you can get the data between that 2 dates. [More info on logical operator here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773.aspx).

**UPDATE**

If you want Use `OR` in filter then use as below

```
 Expression: =(Fields!Start_Date.Value >= 05/04/2012) OR (Fields!Start_Date.Value < 04/04/2013 ) OR (Fields!End_Date.Value < 04/04/2013)
 Operator: =
 Value:  =TRUE
```

Comment: Thankyou @Coder of Code.  I have a question over how to apply this to an SSRS filter as "start date between X and X" is fine with the conditions that are set in the filter, adding the further "or" conditions is the tough part.  I am trying to capture the data for the weeks included within for 12/13 for the conditions of a) started in 11/12 but ended in 12/13, b) started and ended in 12/13, and finally c) started in 12/13 but finished in 13/14

Comment: I am unable to understand your business logic but the conditions you are given for that you can use the expression as I have updated my answer .

Comment: Thankyou @coder of code I will give that a whirl.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: If this answer helped you please accept it as the answer so question can be closed.